# BLOCK and ALIGN in linker script

Tags: gcc, linker, operating-system, ld, bare-metal

What exactly do the BLOCK and ALIGN commands do in a linker script?  The names seem to speak for themselves; but, I don't see exactly how they are affecting the resulting OS image.

The linker script below is based on the example given by the OSDev Bare Bones example (http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones).

(1) In the resulting image, the .rodata section begins at address 0x1400, and the .data section begins at 0x2400.  Shouldn't the BLOCK(4K) command place .rodata at 0x1000 (or some other multiple of 4KB)?

(2) What does ALIGN(4K) do? The documentation (https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/ld_3.html) indicates that it is just a calculation that returns the current location adjusted to the nearest 4K boundary.  However, the documentation for SECTION doesn't indicate a place for a parameter after the colon (other than an AT command, which isn't present here).

(3) In either case, why have both BLOCK and ALIGN?

```
SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x7c00;
    __start = .;
  .text :
  {
    *(.boot)

    /*
        Magic bytes. 0x1FE == 510.

        We could add this on each Gas file separately with `.word`,
        but this is the perfect place to DRY that out.
        */
     . = 0x1FE;
     SHORT(0xAA55)

        /*
        This is only needed if we are going to use a 2 stage boot process,
        e.g. by reading more disk than the default 512 bytes with BIOS `int 0x13`.
         */
        *(.stage2)
    *(.text)
    }

    /* Read-only data. */
    .rodata BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        LONG(0x11223344) /* just a marker so I can see where the linker places this section */
        *(.rodata)
    }

    /* Read-write data (initialized) */
    .data BLOCK(4K) : ALIGN(4K)
    {
        LONG(0x44332211)
        *(.data)
    }
```

Comment: I did find this linker script documentation that seems to better explain things after the colon: http://www.emprog.com/support/documentation/thunderbench-Linker-Script-guide.pdf

Comment: `BLOCK` and `ALIGN` are synonymous (both do the same thing and exist for backwards compatibleness with older linkers). The `ALIGN` after the colon shouldn't be neded but it won't hurt given that there is an ALIGN before the colon already. `ALIGN` over `BLOCK` is preferred. As for the 0x1400 discrepancy that is the difference between 0x9000 and 0x7c00. The first byte in the file will assumed to be loaded into physical memory starting at the first value placed in the location counter (in your case `. = 0x7c00`). The first 0x7c00 bytes before 0x7c00 don't appear in the file (waste of space)

Comment: 0x7c00 + 0x1400 = 0x9000 and 0x9000 is 4kb aligned. You have to account for the fact that the first byte in the image will physically be loaded by the bootloader 0x7c00 (not 0x0000)